# Splitting strings based on a delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to break apart a very simple collection of strings that come in the forms of

```
0|0
10|15
30|55
```

etc etc. Essentially numbers that are seperated by pipes.

When I use java's string split function with .split("|"). I get somewhat unpredictable results. white space in the first slot, sometimes the number itself isn't where I thought it should be.

Can anybody please help and give me advice on how I can use a reg exp to keep ONLY the integers?

I was asked to give the code trying to do the actual split. So allow me to do that in hopes to clarify further my problem :)

```
String temp = "0|0";
String splitString = temp.split("|");
```

results

```
\n
0
| 
0
```

I am trying to get

```
0
0
```

only. Forever grateful for any help ahead of time :)

Comment: Using `.split` is going to be the easiest way, if they are always delimited by something as simple as a pipe. Instead of trying to do this with regex, can you post the code you've written that tries to do the split along with the output (don't just describe the output, show us the output), so we can see what's happening?

Comment: Post some code. Ideally a minimal example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I have posted the two lines of code which is giving me the issue. Thank you for reminding me to post it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I still suggest to use `split()`, it skips null tokens by default. you want to get rid of non numeric characters in the string and only keep pipes and numbers, then you can easily use `split()` to get what you want. or you can pass multiple delimiters to split (in form of regex) and this should work:

```
String[] splited = yourString.split("[\\|\\s]+");
```

and the regex:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?=([\\|\\s\\r\\n]))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: this is actually opposite of what i'd like to do haha! Additionally putting this reg ex in my java ide (net beans) it gives me an illegal escape character error (I didn't even know you could get this error inside a string...). Can you tell me how to keep only the integers?

Comment: @SelcukBor oops, I forgot to escape backslashes. (the problem of posting code without testing). Edited my answer.

Comment: this did the trick :)!!! Thank you so much for saving me in this dark hour. Additionally as commented on in another answer, looks like we needed two escape characters. So it should be split.("[\\|\\s]+");

Comment: You do not need to escape the pipe with a backslash in a character class. What's more, in your second regex, you have one pipe too many.

Comment: @fge that's a habit; escaping special characters in `regex` character class is optional. and thanks for `you have one pipe too many`.

Answer (score 7):

The pipe symbol is special in a regexp (it marks alternatives), you need to escape it. Depending on the java version you are using this could well explain your unpredictable results.

```
class t {
    public static void main(String[]_)
    {
        String temp = "0|0";
        String[] splitString = temp.split("\\|");

        for (int i=0; i<splitString.length; i++)
            System.out.println("splitString["+i+"] is " + splitString[i]);
    }       
}
```

outputs

```
splitString[0] is 0
splitString[1] is 0
```

Note that one backslash is the regexp escape character, but because a backslash is also the escape character in java source you need two of them to push the backslash into the regexp.

Comment: very helpful to know about the special symbols. It helped solve the problem greatly. Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do replace white space for pipes and split it.

```
String test = "0|0 10|15 30|55";
test = test.replace(" ", "|");
String[] result = test.split("|");
```

Hope this helps for you..

Comment: as above, but if you need to keep them in pairs use a different char e.g. String test = "0:0|10:15|30:55"; then create a loop to go through the pairs and split those into your new array

Answer (score 3):

You can use StringTokenizer.

```
String test = "0|0";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(test);
int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); //will parse out the first number
int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); //will parse out the second number
```

Of course you can always nest this inside of a while loop if you have multiple strings.

Also, you need to import java.util.* for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

The pipe ('|') is a special character in [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax). It needs to be "escaped" with a '\' character if you want to use it as a regular character, unfortunately '\' is a special character in Java so you need to do a kind of double escape maneuver e.g.

```
String temp = "0|0";
String[] splitStrings = temp.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library has a nice class [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) which is a much more convenient alternative to `String.split()`. The advantages are that you can choose to split the string on specific characters (like '|'), or on specific strings, or with regexps, and you can choose what to do with the resulting parts (trim them, throw ayway empty parts etc.).

For example you can call

```
Iterable<String> parts = Spliter.on('|').trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split("0|0")
```

Comment: while I appreciate the heads up I am not looking forward to trying and getting a third party library inside the project haha! Things are hard enough to pick up as it is right now. I will book mark this for future use.

Comment: I can understand this, but be assured that Guava is a really helpful library that makes programming in Java much more convenient in a lot of cases. So you should definitively take a look at it when you have some spare time.

Comment: Think of Guava in the same category as Apache Commons. It provides some really useful basic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
([0-9]+)
```

Comment: this gets rid of the integers? I'd like to keep only them XD!

Comment: You would use this in `Pattern.compile()` if you wanted to use a regexp to match the digits out of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a scenario where in we have read a line from csv or xls file in the form of string and need to separate the columns in array of string depending on delimiters.

Below is the code snippet to achieve this problem..

```
         
    { ...
    ....
    String line = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your file"));
    String[] splittedString = StringSplitToArray(stringLine,"\"");
    ...
    ....
    }
    public static String[] StringSplitToArray(String stringToSplit, String delimiter) 
    {  
        StringBuffer token = new StringBuffer();
        Vector tokens = new Vector();
        char[] chars = stringToSplit.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i  0) {
               tokens.addElement(token.toString());
               token.setLength(0);
               i++;
         }
         } else {
                 token.append(chars[i]);
             }
         }
         if (token.length() > 0) {
             tokens.addElement(token.toString());
         }
         // convert the vector into an array
         String[] preparedArray = new String[tokens.size()];
         for (int i=0; i < preparedArray.length; i++) {
             preparedArray[i] = (String)tokens.elementAt(i);
         }
         return preparedArray;
    }
```

Above code snippet contains method call to StringSplitToArray where in the method converts the stringline into string array splitting the line depending on the delimiter specified or passed to the method. Delimiter can be comma separator(,) or double code(").

For more on this, follow this [link](http://scrapillars.blogspot.in/2014/04/split-string-depending-on-delimiter-in.html) : http://scrapillars.blogspot.in